# ASP.NET page automatically scrolling to the bottom

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a very big asp.net page.
It has a lot of javascript and modal panels. It uses ModalPopupExtender control (Microsoft Ajax Library).

The pages loads ok, all my javascript code executes ok, but suddenly the screen scrolls to the bottom. I don't know why.

At the bottom there are a lot of hidden divs (used in the popups) and the modalpopupextender control for each one.

It happens only on Chrome.

Any idea?

Comment: does this happen after a refresh while your at the bottom of the page?

Comment: I am in the same project. It happens after page load completes and all my javascript is executed. If I debug using firebug I can see that:
1- The screen is in the top
2- Page load executes
3- My javascripts executes
4- Some AjaxControlToolkit initialization js code executes
5- After I step over the las js sentence (ajaxcontroltoolkit initialization) the screens scrolls to the bottom

Comment: Does this happen with all the major browers?

Comment: Oh! I didn´t tryied with other browsers. I happens only on Chrome!

Answer (score 0):

Is the focus being set to one of your `divs` How about using

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AServerControl.Focus();
}
```

Comment: It happens after all my custom js is executed. And only on Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Is one of your javascript files calling animate scrolltop at any point?  If it's scrolling to the bottom, the code would look similar to this...

```
$(control).animate({ scrollTop: $(control).height() });
```

Comment: I couldn't find this (I am in the same project)